# oauth authorization with asana (redirect url)

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, authorization, asana

I need to make an authorization with asana in my app. I'm using OAuth2Client library for oauth authorization.

Configuring:

```
    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] setClientID:@"my_clientID"
                                         secret:@"my_client_secret"
                               authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize"]
                                       tokenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token"]
                                    redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000"]// <-- this is the problem part
                                 forAccountType:@"myService"];
```

Requesting:

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] requestAccessToAccountWithType:@"myService"];
```

It launches Safari with authorization, asks me about permissions and then it redirect to `redirectURL`. But what `redirectURL` should I use (here and in account settings), to redirect back to my application? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a custom URI handler, like "myapp://oauth/asana", and configuring your app to be registered to `myapp://` (of course, replacing `myapp` with something more specific to, well, your app).